# Не видит свойство обьекта: "Uncaught TypeError"

Tags: javascript

Вот код где я создаю объект и инициализирую его. Потом еще один объект и пытаюсь связать их через прототип, но не могу получить доступ к свойству предка... выходит ошибка "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop2' of undefined"

```
function car2(amount)
{
    this.prop = amount;
}
var yii = car2(100);

function car3(set)
{
    this.prop2  = set;
}

car3.prototype = yii;
var s = car3(66);
alert(s.prop2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объекты необходимо создавать при помощи оператора `new`:

```js
function car2(amount) {
  this.prop = amount;
}

function car3(set) {
  this.prop2 = set;
}

car3.prototype = new car2(100);

var s = new car3(66);
console.log(s);
```

Comment: спасибо )) не увидел